# is it okay for a muslim to respect pronouns?

Tags: halal-haram, transgender

as-salamu alaykum

I have a small page (600 followers) on a social platform, it is for people to send in friend applications so whoever is interested in becoming their friend to text them (I don’t allow relationship posts). My main posts start with the persons pronouns and I have bumped into many people who use he/him or she/her even though the person who’s a female uses he/him and male likewise (sometimes transgenders as well) or they/them. At some point I started feeling like something feels wrong but still respect their pronouns and put it up. Is it wrong to own such an account of helping people find friends and if I can’t call a female by he/him pronouns?

wʿalaykumu as-salām

Answer (score 1):

Seeker's Guidance has addressed this [topic](https://seekersguidance.org/answers/adab/what-is-the-islamic-perspective-on-gender/),

> While being completely unwavering in our own beliefs and lifestyles, we do have to show compassion to others around us and, at the very least, work together to achieve whatever shared goals we have. Looking down with disdain or disgust towards someone who has changed their gender or wants to do so is completely un-Islamic and sinful. Piety, as Ibn Umar told us, is not to ever look down at anyone. [Tafsir al-Tha’labi] We need to show compassion and give advice where possible.

and particularly,

> On a merely practical level, we have to keep to the law of the land however it applies to the use of gender-nonconforming pronouns, and we have to try to not offend people, even if we understand that they are wrong.